# Are binaries generated by Golang portable between Pi versions?

Tags: golang

I installed golang via (on RPi3, Raspbian Stretch)

```
sudo apt install golang
```

Currently `go version` reports

```
go version go1.7.4 linux/arm
```

I successfully compiled and ran some go program that toggles GPIO using "go-rpio" library.

The question is can I copy/move the resulting binary program to RPI2,1, as well other Raspbian distribution (such as Jessie).

How portable is the binary generated by golang?

Answer (score 1):

**"How portable is the binary generated by golang?":**
It depends

- a) on your build process, which CPU Architecture
- b) additional Package Dependencies

  (For example, CGO_ENABLED=1 possible ? In my example it wasn`t, cause my Golang 
    Binary got C Dependencies as well)

Generally building a golang binary and run it on other distribution "out of the box" is not 100% right. There could be always some "hidden" Dependencies which prevents your binary to be **"static"** , even if you`re trying to import it to another Distribution.

Additional Link to "Static Golang Binaries: https://medium.com/@diogok/on-golang-static-binaries-cross-compiling-and-plugins-1aed33499671

Hope I Could answer your Question.